# Using setState in reactJs with an object always remains empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this snippet that doesn't seem to be work and it is driving me insane! Can someone please point out what I have done wrong ?

```
getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        modalUser: {},
        users: []
    };
},
updateModalUser: function (user) {
    console.log(user);
    module.React.addons.update(this.state, {
        modalUser: { $set: user }
    });
    console.log(this.state);
},
```

I did try doing this originally without the addons, but I had the same result. i.e. my updateModalUser looked like:

```
updateModalUser: function (user) {
    console.log(user);
    this.setState({
        modalUser: user
    });
    console.log(this.state);
},
```

This output I get either way is:

```
Object {id: 28, fname:"fred", lname:"flinstone"…}

Object {modalUser: {}, users: []}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.setState()` is async, you need to log the state in it’s callback:

```
updateModalUser: function (user) {
    console.log(user);
    this.setState({
        modalUser: user
    }, function() {
        console.log(this.state);
    })
}
```

More info here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate

Comment: Thank you! that worked!... I tried wrapping console.log(this.state) within a setTimeout 2000, but that can't have been long enough!

Answer (score -1):

You should use `this.setState({modalUser: newObjectHere})`, which is the correct way of altering a component's state.

Comment: That is what I did. I have edited the example above to try and point this out.